Why does javascript output the same, even when I negate the condition?
I am a student, and I am doing a project for school.
While I was working on it, I encountered a problem and discovered something weird.
I needed to check if a something is null or a empty string, but for some reason it didn't work.
Here's the code snippet:
if(!data.data == null && !data.data == 'null' && !data.data == ''){ // Some code here... }
It didn't work, so I tried this:
console.log(!data.data == null)
console.log(!data.data == 'null')
console.log(!data.data == '')

and when the data.data wasn't empty, the output was this:Console output: false false true
So i change it to:
console.log(data.data == null)
console.log(data.data == 'null')
console.log(data.data == '')

(the data.data value is the same)
the output changed to this:Console output: false false false
So I tried to test this in consoleJavascript console
Here's it copied:
var data = 'aaa'
console.log(data)
aaa
console.log(data == null)
false
console.log(!data == null)
false
console.log(!data == '')
true
console.log(data == '')
false
console.log(!data === null)
false
console.log(data === null)
false
data = null
null
console.log(data === null)
true
console.log(!data === null)

So the question is, When the value is not null, why does it always output false, even when I negate it, but when the value is null, negating it works?
PS: I am sorry if this is a stupid question, or not too clear, but I am not that good, and really confused right now

Did you mean to type !=?

basically !data is not part of operator  == , so you are negating the var only. which is true and true == null is false

Maybe you meant !(data == null) instead of !data == null?

evolutionxbox yes, I am sorry for the confusion, but I am still confused why it works with == ''

because false is loosely equal to an empty string. https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

@AhmedSunny Oh, thanks! But Why does it work with  == ''?

@001 Yes, thank you. I am still kinda confused why it worked sometimes, and sometimes not...

!"aaa" is false and In javascript, is an empty string always false as a boolean?

Other things to learn are, "operator precedence" and "type coercion"

The fundamental issue here is where you are putting the exclamation marks in your code.
When you write !data == null, javascript does two things:

It evaluates the expression !data - which will return false if data is truthy (generally speaking - if it has a value that is not false or zero). It applies the logical NOT operator
Then, it takes that value and checks if it equals null. It will never equal null - because the expression !data will be a boolean - either true or false - but NEVER null.

It will do the first action (negating the value) first per JavaScript's operation precedence. You could reverse that precedence by writing !(data == null), which ill give a result more similar to what you are trying to do.
What you probably meant to do was data != null - which will check wether data is not equal null. This is called the inequality operator.

Oh, ok. Thanks a lot!

Were you able to get this to work by switching to !=?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_precedence is relevant here

You need to understand how data behaves when it has a value, such as data = 'aaa'. In this case, data will hold the value 'aaa'. However, if you check !data, it will evaluate whether data has a value; if there is no value, !data will return false.
When you use the comparison operator == with false, all values like 0, "0", "" will be coerced into false. Therefore, when comparing 0 == false or "" == false, the result will be true.
When you use the strict equality operator ===, it not only compares the values but also checks the data types.

"it will evaluate whether data has a value;" no, just checks truthyness and inverses it

"if there is no value, !data will return false" not at all. Try data = "aaa"; console.log(!data)

"all values like 0, "0", """ incomplete - like what? What is the common thing between them and how would one know what other values belong to this group?
